# bootstrap: Can't create a navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `twitter bootstrap v3` to create a navbar and I follow their [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar)

```
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="brand" href="/">Title</a>
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/feedback">Feedback</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/me" target="_blank">whoami</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But the navbar is not created. Here is the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/EJUeIrIY1OiiU9OChDem?p=preview)

What is that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at **wrong** version of docs(v.2.3.2), the correct documentation for v3.0.0 is [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) and that fixed my issue

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex5-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex5-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </nav>
```

The demo is updated and can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/EJUeIrIY1OiiU9OChDem?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you need the class "navbar-nav" on your ul :

```
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that you can change h1 for a link directly in the nav like this:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hello Plunker!</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that documentation page doesnt work for you is because it's using a different style sheet.

If you use that documentation page's stylesheet..it'll work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

Documentation is just old.